# What is the size of the cell that I should put in cellForRow for grouped table?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

**Note:** It's obvious that the width is 300. I am not entirely sure because after I give a cell with 300 width, the cell is resized to 320. The reason I asked is because in one case I give 300 and in another I give 320 and both works fine. I wonder if there is an official way.

I am not asking what the width of the cell for grouped cell. I am asking what's the width of the cell that I should supply. I sometimes send 300 width cells and 320 cells without problem.

I use xib and subclass the UITableViewCell. Has done it multiple times. It works. I am just curious if there is just some official documentation that when groupped you need to return tableViewCell that's 20 points narrower than UITableViewCell, because I am not seeing that anywhere.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NearbyShortcutTableViewCell * cell;

    if([self.arrayOfItems[row] isNotEmpty]){
        cell=(NearbyShortcutTableViewCell *)self.arrayOfItems[row];
    }
    PO(cell);
    PO(cell.superview);
    PO(cell.superview.superview);
    return cell;
}


cell.superview.superview: (null)
     cell: <NearbyShortcutTableViewCell: 0x89a8300; baseClass = UITableViewCell;
 frame = (0 0; 300 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x89a8420>>
     cell.superview: (null)
     cell.superview.superview: (null)
     cell: <NearbyShortcutTableViewCell: 0x89a9030; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 300 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x89f3d60>>
     cell.superview: (null)
     cell.superview.superview: (null)
     cell: <NearbyShortcutTableViewCell: 0x8bbf5e0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 754; 320 50); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bbf700>>
     cell.superview: (null)
     cell.superview.superview: (null)
     cell: <NearbyShortcutTableViewCell: 0x8bb48b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 704; 320 50); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bbe6d0>>
     cell.superview: (null)
     cell.superview.superview: (null)
     cell: <NearbyShortcutTableViewCell: 0x8bb4050; baseClass = UITableViewCell; 
frame = (0 654; 320 50); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bbe2c0>>
```

So in the beginning I provide a 300 width cell. Somehow it got resized into 320. However, everything remains "fine"

Actually should I provide a 300 width cell or a 320 width cell anyway?

It seems that no matter the size of the cell that I provide, the cell itself will be resized to the width of the tableViewCell. I just don't want to handle the subviews layouting when size is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard size for a **Plain** `UITableVIewCell` is **320 x 44** where as a **Grouped** cell is about **300 x 44** (with a border on either side of **10**). You can change this to whatever you want as it all depends on the content and preference of you the developer on how you want to present your views.

Typically, if you are n't doing anything fancy with the tableView, (i.e its going to fill the whole screen), you can just skip sizing the cells or table altogether.

Comment: Okay I provided 300 width cells, why iOS turn that into a 320 width cell? Also why the superview is nil? And why everything "just works"? How does it work?

Comment: That's where the problem is. It seems that no matter what the size of the cell is it'll always be resized to fit the tableView width.

Comment: Make sure the Auto resize masks are not set. You haven't provided much information but I assume you are using an XIB.

Comment: Yes. Actually autoresize mask doesn't matter because it's automatically changed to W either.

Comment: I use xib and subclass the UITableViewCell. Has done it multiple times. It works. I am just curious if there is just some official documentation that when groupped you need to return tableViewCell that's 20 points narrower than UITableViewCell, because I am not seeing that anywhere.